# Most efficient way to prove that $K$ is compact then $K$ is bounded in $R^k$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that if a set $K \subset X$ is compact then $K$ is bounded (we are also given that we are in $R^k$, even though this is true in arbitrary $(X,d)$. I think I found a way that works, but I don't know if it's so efficient or not.

---

$K$ is compact, so for an open cover $\{G_\alpha\}$ it has a finite cover $\{G_n\}$. Let $p_i$ be the centers of the neighborhoods that make up this finite cover, with associated radius $r_i$.

For each $q_i \in N_{r_i} (p_i)$, we have that $q_i$ is in the neighborhood around $p_1$ with radius $d(p_1, p_i) + r_i$. Indeed, $d(p_1, q_i) \leq d(p_1, p_i) + d(p_i, q_i) < d(p_1, p_i) + r_i$.

Then let $R = \displaystyle \max_{i \geq 1} (d(p_1, p_i) + r_i)$. Then choose any $r > R$, then $K \subset \{G_n\} \subset N_r (p_i)$, so $K$ is bounded.

---

Is this a more efficient way to prove it? Is there a faster way that can take advantage of the fact that we are in $R^k$?

Answer (score 5):

Pick a point $p \in K$. Then $\{B(p, j)\}_{j \geq 1}$ is an open cover of $K$, and by compactness it admits a finite subcover $\{B(p, j)\}_{j=j_0}^n$. So $K \subset B(p,n)$.

Comment: That's a nice way to do it. And so much more concise!

Comment: Would you believe me if I told you that I actually saw this yesterday? haha

Comment: Where did you find it? Here on se?

Comment: If you want to be $100\%$ rigorous there, you'll want to notice that the subcover can be something like $B(p,1) \cup B(p,3) \cup B(p, 10) \cup \ldots \cup B(p,n)$, we don't get to pick *which* balls, but this is not important, since we can just "fill in" and still get a finite subcover.

Comment: yeah, I realized that, but I think a reader could figure sense of it why we get to choose.

Comment: I saw it on Folland or Bartle's book, don't remember the exact page now.

Comment: We could say something like: Since $B(p, 1) \subset B(p,2) \subset \dots$, let $j_{max}$ be the largest $j$ in our finite subcover, then $K \subset B(p,j_{max})$.

Comment: Exactly! The maximum is attained because of finiteness.